# rspec-rails 2.11.1 + rails 3.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bundler, rspec-rails

I'm using rspec-rails 2.11.0 in my app, but when I execute rspec spec/ something wrong happens. This is stack of error:

```
/Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup': You have already activated rspec-core 2.10.1, but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.11.1. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
from /Users/diego/Development/Rails/carros/carros-web/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/diego/Development/Rails/carros/carros-web/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/diego/Development/Rails/carros/carros-web/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/diego/Development/Rails/carros/carros-web/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/diego/Development/Rails/carros/carros-web/spec/models/admin_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `map'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

What's is wrong? This is my gem file  https://gist.github.com/3280825

Comment: does `bundle exec rspec spec` work?

Comment: I tried but some tests no works. I go try again. Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that your rspec app version is different from the one you have in global env.

And it seems when you execute rspec the one from global is being used.

The way to make it work is to use `bundle exec` as said from @prusswan wich will execute that command with the app env (with proper gems versions etc..)

Also the error message mentions to try `bundle exec`

Answer (score 0):

Since bundler is used, although the error message says to "try" `bundle exec`, you *really* have to run it with bundle exec if you want to ensure that only the gem versions specified in `Gemfile/Gemfile.lock` are used. The other alternative would be to use binstubs as explained [here](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2011/07/18/stop-typing-bundle-exec/).

Comment: The problem is occurring why in my computer I have two versions of the rspec?

Comment: You may have had an older version used by another project, or the current project previously (`bundle update` upgrades the gems in use to newer versions but does not remove the older ones). If you are really bothered, you can attempt to remove specific gem versions by `gem uninstall rspec`.